# How to know if Perl Mojo::DOM::find returns or matches any DOM Element

Tags: html, perl, dom, mojolicious

Am currently parsing a series of webpages with [`Mojo::DOM`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) and the only criterion for me to proceed down the web page is if there's an element found within.

I have my DOM object built like this:

```
my $urlMJ = Mojo::URL->new($entry->link);
my $tx = $ua->get($urlMJ);
my $base = $tx->req->url;
my $dom = $tx->res->dom;
my $divVideo = $dom->find('div#searchforme');
```

My question is, how do I know if `$divVideo` is empty?

I realise that from this question on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mojolicious/w3BxShahJGs/HGxyg3jQGCYJ) and [grokbase](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mojolicious/13bhqyg2x4/problem-with-mojo-dom) answered by SRI (Riedel), if `find` doesn't match any element, it returns (if I get it correctly) the DOM object collection initiating the `find` and an empty DOM collection, which happens to be the result.

I thought of using an `each` to get to the empty DOM collection within, but won't the DOM returned contain the initial DOM structure?

I have tried using `if (defined($divVideo))` , I also tried dumping with `print Dumper($divVideo)`. All it returned was `$VAR1 = bless( [], 'Mojo::Collection' );`

I tried `$dom->find('div#searchforme')->size` , return values was `0` and even for those web pages that didn't fall into this category.

Can somebody please help me out?

Is my approach to this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if find doesn't match any element, it returns (if I get it correctly) the DOM object collection initiating the find and an empty DOM collection, which happens to be the result.

You're misunderstanding `find`. It returns *just* a [`Mojo::Collection`](http://metacpan.org/module/Mojo::Collection) of `Mojo::DOM` objects that represent each matching element in the page. Nothing else. So if no matches are found, just an empty collection is returned

This object has a `size` method, so you can say

```
my $divColln = $dom->find('div#searchforme');

if ( $divColln->size > 0 ) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `each` method to convert the collection into a list, and assign it to an array like this

```
my @divColln = $dom->find('div#searchforme')->each;

if ( @divColln ) {
    ...
}
```

Or if you are expecting to find just *one* such element (which it looks like you're doing here) then you can just pick the first item from the collection, like this

```
my $divVideo = $dom->find('div#searchforme')->[0];

if ( $divVideo ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Borodin for the Quick response. I did a print of `$divVideo->size` but it all returned a `0` value, even for all webpages that have the element

Comment: Then either your selector is wrong or you're mistaken about the HTML. `div#searchforme` looks for an element like `<div id="searchforme">`. Did you mean to use `div.searchforme`? It's also possible that the page is partly built using JavaScript, and `Mojo::UserAgent` can't support that. Trying printing `$dom->to_string` to see if the HTML is what you think it is

Comment: you're right @Borodin, the page is partly built with javascript, when Mojo::UserAgent get's the page, those element's haven't been written in. I'll use another approach then. It's actually a DIV #id. Thanks so much man.